# how can i change the language in messages in input tag

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, capacitor

i'm building a web app with capacitor js and react js.

i'm creating a button to when i click the button to upload image file.

[image]

in android it works well, but in ios when i click the button it prints three options like above picture.

i want to make those options to korean.

i knew the language of the messages are depends on system language.

so i already checked the system language setting by window.navigator.language

it already setted in korean.

and then i dont know reason why, it prints in korean when i open a app in native safari browser.

this problem only occurs when i open the web in the app i built by capacitor

someone please give me some hints .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [development region](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundledevelopmentregion) in your `ios/App/App/Info.plist` file:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>ko</string>
```